# cross domain header to get JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, apache, .htaccess, cross-domain

I am working on project that needs to download JSON files from different server and since i am working on jQuery i expected that would be an easy to achieve task.

Here is my code:

```
    loadJSON: function () {
        var ajaxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://dl.sniper.pl/q/test.json"
        ajaxhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        ajaxhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        ajaxhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajaxhttp.readyState == 4 && ajaxhttp.status == 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(ajaxhttp.responseText);
                    console.log(data)
            }
        }
        ajaxhttp.send(null);
    },
```

This example works fine however it uses proxy cors-anywhere.herouapp.com which was suggested to me in different thread. **What i want to achieve is to have an opportunity to get JSON file directly from my server**. I do not want to use third party providers that may be not reliable.

I tried to change .htaccess file to:

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

I've put it .htaccess in directory i store JSON files however without any luck - my chrome always says that i am violating policy or sth like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dl.sniper.pl/q/test.json. Response
>   for preflight is invalid (redirect)

I've been told that's because my server doesnt provide correct headers. I am not sure how to check if it is true or find any remedy for that. Consider i am just end-user of server and i have no rights to change apache settings (or to check if it is apache server).
can you please help me to solve problem and get cross-domain data with JSON? Thank you.